# PySNMP Missing files

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

I have found the following example script to import custom MIBs into PySNMP:

```
import pysnmp
from pysmi.reader import FileReader, HttpReader
from pysmi.searcher import StubSearcher
from pysmi.writer import CallbackWriter
from pysmi.parser import SmiStarParser
from pysmi.codegen import JsonCodeGen
from pysmi.compiler import MibCompiler
# from pysmi import debug

# debug.setLogger(debug.Debug('reader', 'compiler'))

inputMibs = ['***.mib']
srcDirectories = ['C:/PROJECT/SNMPTest/Venv']

def printOut(mibName, jsonDoc, cbCtx):
    print('\n\n# MIB module %s' % mibName)
    print(jsonDoc)

# Initialize compiler infrastructure

mibCompiler = MibCompiler(
    SmiStarParser(), JsonCodeGen(), CallbackWriter(printOut)
)

# search for source MIBs here
mibCompiler.addSources(*[FileReader(x) for x in srcDirectories])
print('Step0')
# never recompile MIBs with MACROs
mibCompiler.addSearchers(StubSearcher(*JsonCodeGen.baseMibs))
print('Step1')
# run recursive MIB compilation
results = mibCompiler.compile(*inputMibs)

print('\n# Results: %s' % ', '.join(['%s:%s' % (x, results[x]) for x in results]))
```

Which returns the following:

**Results: SNMPv2-CONF:missing, SNMPv2-SMI:missing, SNMPv2-TC:missing, MyMIB:failed**

But in my **.mib file, I find all the imports. Any tips on why this is not working?

Answer (score 1):

You should have all these MIB files in `C:/PROJECT/SNMPTest/Venv` as they are the dependencies that are essential for the whole compilation process to succeed.

One problem I can anticipate relates to Windows paths... So try to enable pysmi debugging to make sure the path is not crumbled somehow...